# Vegan alternative to Mozzarella

Tags: cheese, vegan, mozzarella

I'm familiar with many fine vegan cheeses, ranging from cream-cheese to Camambert. Undoubtedly much progress has been made in this area in recent years. The one (important) cheese I have yet to find a suitable replacement for is Mozzarella.

More specifically, I'm interested in a vegan cheese substitute which successfully mimics both the flavor and texture of melted Mozzarella. All soy-based substitutes I've tried which did have stringy properties suffered from very high stickiness, and adhered to the roof of the mouth resulting in an unpleasant experience.

Another recipe I've tried is cashew based cheese combined with tapioca flour, though both flavor and texture were less than adequate.

Comment: Good luck, I think you'll need it (I have met vegan "mozzerlla", and not been impressed.) The vegan cutlet it was on top of was "better than meat" while the "cheese" was grated "stuff" that didn't melt properly.

Comment: All the recipes based on tapioca (for various vegan cheeses) that i found even somewhat working also use agar and some saturated fat...

Comment: If you search for moxarella you will find a cashew/tapioca recipe.  I've not tried it but it claims to act like mozzarella

Comment: Daiya? Btw, for anyone interested we have a vegan/vegetarian related proposal ongoing -http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94068/veganism-and-vegetarianism

Answer (score 5):

Late but you have to try the vegan Mozzarella from Miyoko's kitchen. Its the only Vegan Mozz I've found that tastes great cold i.e. in a caprese sandwich but it also melts very well as I use it on pizza all the time. It may be sold locally in your area I would use their retail location finder.

https://shop.miyokoskitchen.com/products/fresh-buffalo-style-mozzarella-cheese?variant=5781995395

Answer (score 2):

The "[Mozzarisella](http://www.mozzarisella.co.uk/)" is based on rice and goes relatively close to the original one, unluckily it may not be so easy to find it. Personally I've never encountered it outside Italy.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite vegan mozarella is [Teese Vegan Mozarella](http://chicagoveganfoods.com/products/teese-vegan-cheese/) from [Chicago Vegan Foods](http://chicagoveganfoods.com). Indeed, a vegetarian friend of mine who does eat dairy actually prefers Teese on pizza to dairy cheese. Chicago Vegan Foods recently discontinued retail sale of Teese, though it's still available to food services. You can contact them to find an up-to-date list of distributors. (For example, the closest distributor to me is Pizza Pi Vegan Pizzaria in Seattle.)

Answer (score 0):

Violife produces a vegan [mozzarella block](https://violifefoods.com/product/mozzarella-flavour-block/) that serves as a very workable alternative to mozzarella produced from cow's milk. I've personally tested it out on burgers and found it to melt in a very satisfactory way, without any hint of the stringiness of Daiya shreds. It was also deemed good enough by [Pizza Hut](https://www.pizzahut.co.uk/restaurants/blog/vegan-pizza/) who now offers Violife vegan cheese as an option for their pizzas in some countries.